# Generating functions for $E$ and $H$ waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waveguide

I know different forms of how Maxwell's equations are transformed when it is assumed to be in a cylindrical guide with any cross section, but I had never seen this:

[image]

References about provenance are: *Theory of Slots in Rectangular Wave-guides* - A.F.Stevenson - Journal of Applied Physics.
I also add that the functions $\psi$ and $\Psi$ are the solutions of the wave equation in scalar form:

$$\nabla ^ 2 \psi + k ^ 2 \psi = 0$$
$$\nabla ^ 2 \Psi + k ^ 2 \Psi = 0$$

I thought we could get the initial expressions using the electrodynamic potentials with some suitable gauge, but in any case I don't explain the absence of a potential vector.

Could anyone give me the idea of how to prove them?

PS: in the article, these functions are referred as 'generating functions for E and H waves'.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of equations is the sum of TM (E) and TE (H) modes, where $\psi$ is for TE and $\Psi$ for TM. Notice that if $\frac {\partial}{\partial z}$ were to be set $\mathfrak{j} k$ then both $E_z$ and $H_z$ would be zero but of course that is not true around the discontinuity where they are concentrated and non-propagating. In fact, to calculate the impedance of the slot one has to calculate the stored, i.e., non-propagating energy around the discontinuity.

Comment: Do you have references? Or could you link a proof of this, please? Thank you.